# PHP WEB CRAWLER

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code, I narrowed it down to a logical error in my `if` statement, (I think), I want to output if the site crawled is using Google analytics. instead of

```
return (NULL);
```

Should I be returning the value of $flag_ga like so:

```
if (stristr($inside_script[0][$i], "ga.js"))
        $flag_ga = TRUE;
      else
        $flag_ga = FALSE;
}
return $flag_ga;
```

Not sure where I screwed up here. Below is the full code:

```
class track {


    function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
     if(!$this->isCli()) die("Please use php-cli!");
     if (!function_exists('curl_init')) die("Please install cURL!");
      $this->hp = $arg1;
      $this->rlevel = $arg2;
      $this->rmax = $arg3;
    }


    function isCli() {
     return php_sapi_name()==="cli";
    }


    function getContent() {
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->hp);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $content = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
      return $content;
    }



    function checkGA($content) {

      $flag_ga      = false;

      $script_regex = "/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/i";

      preg_match_all($script_regex, $content, $inside_script);

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($inside_script[0]); $i++)
      {
      if (stristr($inside_script[0][$i], "ga.js"))
        $flag_ga = TRUE;
      else
        return (NULL);

      }

    }

}

/*
 *
 * Echo Output
 *
 */

 $track_obj = new track();

 $ga = $track_obj->checkGA($content);

 if ($ga == NULL) {
  echo "USING GA: NO\r\n";
 }
 else {
  echo "USING GA: YES\r\n";
 }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: look at the return, you return either NULL or nothing, TRUE can never be returned from that function

Comment: That is not an informative title.

Comment: Have you tried making the change you suggested yourself? Is there some reason you think this is *not* the solution to your problem?